# Must declare the table variable , < operator .addwithvalue exception

Tags: c#, sql

I am having some trouble with the following sql command. Firstly
When I run the following query I get the exception 'Incorrect syntax near '@IQueryType'.' However when I replace @IQueryType in the command with the < symbol it works fine. Secondly I get the exception 'Must declare the table variable "@ATable"' ATable is just a string containing the value "customers". Any help is appreciated

```
    using (SqlCommand isTrue = new SqlCommand("SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(select * from @ATable where @AField @IQueryType @NTestValue and date_time_CCM > dateadd(hh,-@TPeriod,getdate()))THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END", con))
            {
                isTrue.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ATable", (String)ATable);
                isTrue.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AField",(String)AField);
                isTrue.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IQueryType",(String) "<");
                isTrue.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NTestValue", NTestValue);
                isTrue.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TPeriod", 1);

                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = isTrue.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    Active = dr[0].ToString();
                }
                con.Close();
                Console.WriteLine(Active + " this is the result you want");
            }
```

Comment: You cannot parameterize table names, column names, or logic operators.

Comment: Nor operators - parameters != text replacement

Comment: You can only parameterize *values*, not table names, column names or operators.

Comment: okay, thanks, would there be any solution to this, like using string.Format on the command maybe ?

Comment: @jOE127 Yes, that is how you could handle this.  Of course that opens you up to potential sql injection.  You'd have to do your own verification of the values before formatting them into your query string to avoid that.

Comment: Either that or use dynamic SQL statements... But both of those methods are too error prone!

Comment: Right ya, SQL injection shouldn't be too much of a problem as it is a console app for running on a local machine and where input is taken users can only select from drop down menus, Thanks for the help